# exercise 14 learning python the hard way

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Here is the code from the exercise:

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print "Where do you live %s?" % user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r.  Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer.  Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Now I am running Windows 7 and I am running the CMD line with the code

```
python ex14.py myname
```

I get this error:

```
File "ex14.py", line 3
Python ex14.py, user_name
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @lc ... err I should think the question is 'why does it error on line 3 in the string formatting code? (btw I believe using % for string formatting is now depreceated and you should use format.()

Comment: script, user_name = argv   is unpacking the array.  I would print argv just before this and make sure it is what you are expecting.  Also check your white space.  btw this works just fine on my linux box.

Comment: @PaulSullivan -- While `.format` is more powerful and worth learning these days, % formatting is still alive and well and is not deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

There is [nothing wrong with the script](http://ideone.com/duSzIv) among visible characters.

- check there is no Unicode whitespace in the source e.g., [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=a0&B1=Show) character. Create a new script in the same directory:

```
with open('ex14.py', 'rb') as file:
     s = file.read()
     print(repr(s)[:60])
     u = s.decode('ascii') # this line should raise an error
                           # if there are bytes outside ascii
```

- check Python version to make sure it is 2.7 (to interpret correctly error messages):

  ```
  $ python -V
  ```
- check that the file is not saved using utf-16/32 encodings (@abarnert's suggestion in the comments).

  You should see many zero bytes `'\x00'` in the `repr()` results in this case.

Comment: +1. Another possibility—given that this is Windows—is that the script was saved as UTF-16-LE (rather than something ASCII-compatible, like UTF-8).

Comment: @abarnert: good point. On Ubuntu `utf-16-le` produces `NameError` with the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

install python2 and in terminal type

> python2 ex14.py myname

will solve the problem
you are running the script in the latest python version
and the syntax of your code is for python version 2
that's why you are getting the syntax error